# How can I run shell commands for non-root user during cloud-init configuration?

Tags: linux, shell, cloud, rust-cargo

During installation of a cloud VM with `cloud-init` e.g. when installing Rust toolchain

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
packages:
- apt-transport-https
- build-essential
- cmake
runcmd:
- export RUSTUP_HOME=/opt/rust
- export CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust
- curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | bash -s -- -y --no-modify-path --default-toolchain stable --profile default
```

I also want to execute the toolchain configuration `rustup default stable` in user space so that it is ready to use when user first signs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key element is to determine the (target/adminsitration) user, that is currently installed on the VM with `export USER=$(awk -v uid=1000 -F":" '{ if($3==uid){print $1} }' /etc/passwd)`, so that environment variable `$USER` holds the username during the **cloud-init configuration** process.
Then to use `sudo -H -u $USER` to run a shell in target user's context. Also import is to enhance the user's environment to include the installed toolchain - permanently with extending `.profile` or alike as well as temporarily while executing this shell operation.

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
packages:
- apt-transport-https
- build-essential
- cmake
runcmd:
- export USER=$(awk -v uid=1000 -F":" '{ if($3==uid){print $1} }' /etc/passwd)
- export RUSTUP_HOME=/opt/rust
- export CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust
- curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | bash -s -- -y --no-modify-path --default-toolchain stable --profile default
- echo '\n\n# added by cloud init\nsource /opt/rust/env' >> /home/$USER/.profile
- sudo -H -u $USER bash -c 'source /opt/rust/env && rustup default stable'
```

> check out complete [post](https://community.ops.io/kaiwalter/install-rust-toolchain-management-with-cloud-init-on-an-linux-azure-vm-4dl9) with background information